# Hibernate - duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Pessoa:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_pessoa", schema="public")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Pessoa implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "tb_pessoa_id_seq", sequenceName = "tb_pessoa_id_seq", schema="public")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "tb_pessoa_id_seq")
   @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
   private Integer id;

   ...
```

Pessoa Fisica:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="tb_pessoafisica", schema="public")
@PessoaFisicaAnnotation
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class PessoaFisica extends Pessoa implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Column(name = "email")
   private String email;

   ...
```

Supondo que na tabela **Pessoa** tem registros com **id** de 1 até 500. Quando executo o código abaixo:

```
PessoaFisica pessoaFisica = new PessoaFisica();
pessoaFisica.setEmail("teste@123.com");

...

em.persist(pessoa);
```

Está acontecendo o seguinte erro:

```
17:26:13,613 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-1) ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tb_pessoa_pkey"
    Detalhe: Key (id)=(438) already exists.
17:26:13,614 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-1) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffff7f000101:-7f6ae4e3:558080ed:4f, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@331af73a >: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tb_pessoa_pkey"
  Detalhe: Key (id)=(438) already exists.
```

Não consegui ainda descobrir porque está tentando usar o **id** 438 e não 501

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Muito obrigado

```
CREATE TABLE tb_pessoa
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tb_pessoa_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE tb_pessoafisica
(
    email character varying(64) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tb_pessoafisica_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fkee8c050f70415778 FOREIGN KEY (id)
        REFERENCES tb_pessoa (id) MATCH SIMPLE
)

CREATE SEQUENCE tb_pessoa_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 500
  CACHE 1;
```

Log Hibernate:

```
07:50:52,463 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2) Hibernate: 
07:50:52,463 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)     select
07:50:52,464 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)         nextval ('public.tb_pessoa_id_seq')
07:50:52,497 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2) Hibernate: 
07:50:52,498 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)     insert 
07:50:52,499 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)     into
07:50:52,499 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)         public.tb_pessoa
07:50:52,500 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)         (id) 
07:50:52,500 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)     values
07:50:52,501 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)         (?)
07:50:52,519 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
07:50:52,521 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2) ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tb_pessoa_pkey"
    Detalhe: Key (id)=(438) already exists.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando o seu ORM, o Hibernate irá executar uma consulta para recuperar o próximo valor de `tb_pessoa_id_seq` antes de incluir o novo registro, algo deste tipo:

```
select nextval ('tb_pessoa_id_seq')
```

Citando o que você mesmo disse:

> Supondo que na tabela Pessoa tem registros com id de 1 até 500.

Pois bem, se você verificar o valor de início na sua *sequence* é **467** (`START 467`), ou seja, o próximo será **468**, que é o retornado na consulta pelo próximo valor da *sequence*.

Para corrigir isto você pode executar algo que altere o valor de início da *sequence*, algo assim:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE tb_pessoa_id_seq RESTART WITH 501;
```

Comment: Bruno, muito obrigado pela sua resposta. Realmente  o inicio da minha sequence estava "errado" no exemplo. Alterei para **500** agora o start para tentar "explicar" melhor o meu problema.

Comment: O problema ainda continua, pois se tento persistir a entidade ao invés de usar o último **id + 1** (501) está com 438.

Comment: @Mamga inclua o log do hibernate, com as queries geradas ao inserir

Comment: Olá @bruno-césar - incluído o log do hibernate... Obrigado.

Comment: @Mamga tem certeza que no banco de dados a *sequence* está correta? Simulei seu caso e está certo, bastou alterar. Talvez seja interessante incluir um exemplo reproduzível para verficarmos.

Comment: não sei o que dizer mais. Comecei do zero novamente para ver se não era algo errado no meu fonte, o banco continuou o mesmo, e quando fui persistir um registro aconteceu a mesma coisa. O hibernate usa o `select nextval ('public.tb_pessoa_id_seq')` se eu copio e colo este comando no pgadmin ele retorna o valor correto. Mas no hibernate não.

Comment: @Mamga está conectando no servidor/base corretos, não é? Já tentou criar uma nova base?

Comment: Resolvido, ainda não entendi o porque, mas com uma ajuda inclui o `allocationSize = 1` no `@SequenceGenerator` e voltou a funcionar. Obrigado